# how to create array with same dimension as another array in SAS

Tags: arrays, dynamic, sas

I have a very simple question to which there is probably an obvious answer,... but it keeps eluding me. Maybe someone can help?

The question is this...

I define a period, say

```
%let analysis = y_1005 -- y_1143;
```

where y_1005 define some variables going from year 2010 week 5 to year 2011 week 43. Then from this I define an array

```
array period(*) &analysis;
```

Now I would like to define a second array with the same dimension as the first array, and I figure there is a smart way to do that, such as

```
array new_array(dim(period));
```

But this obviously not work. I have tried various things, but I can't get it to work. How is it possible to call "dim(period)" within the creation of an array, or to do this some other way?

Comment: Just an observation: `array period(*) y_1005 - y_1143` includes a lot of extra variable names that you do not need, such as `y_1053, y_1054, ..., y_1099, y_1100, ...`

Comment: Yes, I noticed that right after I posted the question. Since my variables are right after each other I put y_1005 -- y_1143 (I need to extend the period for other analyses, and there are 53 weeks in some years).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
%let analysis = y_1005 - y_1143;

data test;
    array period(*) &analysis;
    call symput ("n_periods", dim(period));
run;

data test2;
    array new_array(&n_periods.);
run;
```

(See also my comment to your original post)

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with a solution that solves the problem spotted by @stevepastelan, namely the extra variables beyond weeks 52/53.  If you store your start and end periods in separate macro variables and use the WEEKU5. informat (e.g. 10W05 for 2010 week 5), then you can use a DATA *NULL* statement to calculate the number of weeks between the 2 periods and create a macro list of the variable names to use in the array.  I've also used PROC FORMAT to create the required format for the year/week part of the variable name (i.e. 1005).

Hope this helps.

```
%let start=10W05;
%let end=11W43;

proc format;
picture yrwk low-high=%0y%0U (datatype=date);
run;

data _null_;
length varname $10 all_names $1000;
weeks=intck('week',input("&start.",weeku5.),input("&end.",weeku5.));
do i=0 to weeks;
    varname=cats("y_",put(intnx('week',input("&start.",weeku5.),i),yrwk.));
    call catx(' ',all_names,varname);
end;
call symput('weeks',weeks+1); /* start and end weeks are inclusive, so need to add 1 */
call symput('all_names',all_names);
run;

data x;
array period{*} &all_names.;
array new_array{&weeks.};
run;
```

Comment: I think the asker had his variables already created, and was using `--` (double dash) to select them.

Comment: True, I already had the variables and could select them with --. But looking ahead this way of automizing the "week" problem will come in handy. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

[Only an integer constant, range of numbers, or * (asterisk) can be used to dimension an array](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201956.htm)